# Use join into hibernate mapping against main class foreing key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is a simple description of my situation and the requirement I am not able to implement:

I have two tables "address" and "person" related with a FK:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id_person` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_sent_address` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_person`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkSentAddress` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sent_address`) REFERENCES `address` (`id_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I want to create a hibernate mapping using this two tables to create a simple model.

It is important the fact that I NEED to do the mapping using "join" having something like this:

```
<class name="xxx.PersonAndAddress" table="person">

    <id name="idPerson" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_person" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="name"/>

    <join table="address">
        <key column="id_address" />
        <property name="street" column="street" />
        <property name="city" column="city" />
    </join>

</class>
```

**This is not working because the "join" key column "id_address" is creating the mapping against the primary key "id_person", and I don't know how can I change this behaviour column to use the person's "id_sent_address" instead "id_person". Is there any solution?**

As I said, this is a simple situation that describes my real problem, which involves more fields and more logic, but this is the essence of the issue.

Right now I'm using formulas for each address's field but it is a big quantity of fields and I would use join to improve its performance.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you use `ORM`?

Comment: hibernate is a ORM...what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of defining the schema, you can write a class and use `@Entity`. So, you managed your table using `java class`

Comment: I need to use hibernate

Answer (score -1):

Two things, first of all, **ORDER MATTERS**. You need to create your address table first, before you can create your person table, as person table's id_sent_address *DEPENDS* on the id_address from address table.

Secondly, to set up a foreign key, the target key MUST be a key as well, which you forgot to add.

So once the two errors are fixed like below, you should be able to execute it without errors.

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id_person` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_sent_address` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_person`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkSentAddress` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sent_address`) REFERENCES `address` (`id_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: yes the sql has errors but it is only an example of the situation. I have already edited it. 
I'm not asking how can I execute the sql, the question is how can I do the mapping...